# iOS CoreDataGeneratedAccessors and save in one to many

Tags: ios, core-data, accessor, generated

I have used coredata in a project with only a parent and a child [one to many], cd will generate the entity.h and entity.m for NSManagedObject, [ok]
the problem is that in my prior project , the `addCategToEntityObject` in my entityMother.h is

```
- (void)addCategToEntityObject:(NSManagedObject *)value;
```

and it works fine,

but in my new project, the CoreDataGeneratedAccessors
for the entityMother.h is

```
- (void)addTo_InterestObject:(Interest *)value;
```

so I use a kind of same approach to save but now get a warning and in run time crash
off course! [but how to fix it!]

> WARNING: Incompatible Objective-C types 'struct NSManagedObject *', expected 'struct Interest *' when passing argument 1 of 'addTo_InterestsObject' from distinct Objective-C type

here the action for saving with the problem:
    -(IBAction) saveInterest: (id) sender{

```
NSManagedObject *newItem;

NSManagedObjectContext *contextCateg_ = [categ_ managedObjectContext];


NSLog(@"el contexto :%@",contextCateg);

newItem = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Interest" inManagedObjectContext:contextCateg_];


[categ_ addTo_InterestObject:interest_]; //vooddoo! un mensaje del mas alla!



//OJO, COREDATA ME GENERA UN   - (void)addTo_InterestObject:(Interest *)value;
// EN LUGAR De NSManagedObject, 


[newItem setValue:item_new.text forKey:@"interest"];

NSError *error;
[context save:&error];
NSLog(@"ITEM saved");
```

in the .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


 @class Categories, Interest;

 @class EventMAppDelegate;
 @class editContactViewController; 


  @interface BackEndViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,   UITableViewDataSource, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate> {

Categories *categ_; //objetos de los Entities
    Interest *interest_;

NSManagedObjectContext *contextCateg;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused because in the first model, your `Categ` entity had no specified NSManagedObject subclass name defined so the code generator just assigned a generic NSManagedObject value type to the method parameter.

However, in the second model, your `Interest` entity has NSManagedObject subclass name of `Interest` defined so the code generator assigned a type of `Interest` to the method parameter.

As defined, you must pass an object of class `Interest` to the method. If you don't wish to do this, you must remove the class name from the data model and regenerate the code to accept a generic NSManagedObject.

Comment: thanks a lot!, I end up just using 
- (void)addCategToEntityObject:(NSManagedObject *)value; and deleting //- (void)addCategToEntityObject:(Entity *)value; will that have any negative outcome?? thanks a lot!

Comment: Since `Interest` is a NSManagedObject subclass it should work.